# Mocking async query operations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, asynchronous, mocking

I created unit test and I have to mock `context` of my EF. I use `Moq` library and `Xunit`. I have a test method like this:

```
    [Fact]
    public async Task DeleteAttachmentCommandHandler_WithValidCommand_ShouldCallSaveChangesAsyncOnce()
    {
        var command = new DeleteAttachmentCommand { Id = Guid.NewGuid() };
        var attachments = new List<Attachment>();

        var dbSetMock = attachments.AsQueryable().BuildMockDbSetForAsyncQueryOperations();
        _context.Setup(x => x.Set<Attachment>()).Returns(dbSetMock.Object);
        _context.Setup(x => x.SaveChangesAsync(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())).ReturnsAsync(1).Verifiable();

        await Act(command);

        _context.Verify(x => x.SaveChangesAsync(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()), Times.Once);
    }
```

The `_context` is of type `Mock<IEmployeeSettlementsDbContext>`

The `BuildMockDbSetForAsyncQueryOperations` is my extension method thanks to the MSDN documentation -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/testing/mocking, which uses the async providers like `TestDbAsyncEnumerable`, `TestDbAsyncEnumerator`, `TestDbAsyncQueryProvider`. And my extension `BuildMockDbSetForAsyncQueryOperations` looks like this:

```
public static Mock<IDbSet<TEntity>> BuildMockDbSetForAsyncQueryOperations<TEntity>(this IQueryable<TEntity> data) where TEntity : class
    {
        var dbSetMock = new Mock<IDbSet<TEntity>>();

        dbSetMock.As<IDbAsyncEnumerable<TEntity>>().Setup(x => x.GetAsyncEnumerator()).Returns(new TestDbAsyncEnumerator<TEntity>(data.GetEnumerator()));
        dbSetMock.As<IQueryable<TEntity>>().Setup(x => x.Provider).Returns(new TestDbAsyncQueryProvider<TEntity>(data.Provider));
        dbSetMock.As<IQueryable<TEntity>>().Setup(x => x.Expression).Returns(data.Expression);
        dbSetMock.As<IQueryable<TEntity>>().Setup(x => x.ElementType).Returns(data.ElementType);
        dbSetMock.As<IQueryable<TEntity>>().Setup(x => x.GetEnumerator()).Returns(data.GetEnumerator());

        return dbSetMock;
    }
```

In my actual handler method which is testing I have a line:

```
var attachment = await _context.Set<Attachment>()
    .SingleAsync(x => x.Id == command.Id);
```

And when I run the test it fails and show me the message

> Message: System.InvalidOperationException : The sequence does not contain a matching element.

But when I change the query in handler to be `ListAsync()` instead of `SingleAsync()` then the mock is setup correctly and returns me an empty list. But it does not work for the single element using `SingleAsync()`.

EDIT:
Here is my full Handler method:

```
    public async Task<Unit> Handle(DeleteAttachmentCommand command, CancellationToken cancellationToke = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        ValidateCommand(command);

        var attachment = await _context.Set<Attachment>().SingleAsync(x => x.Id == command.Id);
        attachment.IsDeleted = true;

        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return Unit.Value;
    }
```

Comment: Why your `var attachments = new List<Attachment>();` is empty. Please add some dummy data and then check it again.

Comment: @TanvirArjel, I did. The simplest form: `var attachments = new List<Attachment>{ new Attachment() };` - it behavies exactly the same

Comment: No! you are wrong again.Make it `var attachments = new List<Attachment>{ new Attachment(){Id = 1, .....} };` and then `_context.Setup(x => x.Set<Attachment>()).Returns(dbSetMock.Object.Where(x => x.Id == 1));`. Now your problem should be solved. Let me know the update, I shall post it as answer.

Comment: Oh, this way, thanks I will try, but I get an convertion error: `cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Attachment>' to 'System.Data.Entity.IDbSet<Attachment>'` ?

Comment: Yes! give a try and let me know.

Comment: Test fails with the message: `System.ArgumentNullException: The value cannot be null.
The name of the parameter: source`

Comment: Actually your actual code is looking hard to test and that's why it always preferable to write testable code.

Comment: I don't think my code looks hard to test, I try to keep it as simple as possible. I updated my question with the CommandHandler method

Comment: No! No! You are wrong! May be its seems simple but really hard to test, now you have to write a mock DbConext and so on.

Comment: I also did the integration test which passes very well and uses the real DB context and real DB (of course another db for tests). But I wanted also to unit test the validation here and check the 'correct path' that's why i need to mock the context

Comment: Its always better to use `Repository` and` UnitOfWork` pattern to querying data. This makes testing so easy.

Comment: But I consciously did not create another abstraction like `Repository` just for the purpose to keep unit testing easier. I think this is a very bad solution to create another abstraction layer like repository just for the unit tests. EF is like repository pattern itself.

Comment: May be this is your feeling but actually not! By the way wish you all the best.

Answer (score 1):

`SingleAsync()` documentation in [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/dn220221(v%3Dvs.113))

> Asynchronously returns the only element of a sequence, and throws an
>   exception if there is not exactly one element in the sequence.

Consider to use `FirstOrDefault()`or `FirstOrDefaultAsync()` method instead of `SingleAsync()`. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/dn220208(v%3Dvs.113)) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=netframework-4.7.2) are a link about that, this will not throw exception.

Comment: If I changed it to `FirstOrDefaultAsync` it returns me `null` instead of empty `Attachment` element

Comment: I know the difference betweer `First` and `Single`, it's not the point of this question. The mocking EF async operation is not mocking correctly for me, but only for `Single` and `First` (single elements). For list it works ok